# Disable using __sprintf_chk()

Tags: c++, c, printf, fortify-source

I observe that a c++ program uses `sprintf`, where this sprintf implicitly invokes `__sprintf_chk()`.
This `__sprintf_chk()` seems to check buffer overflow by examining stack frames.

For my research purpose, I wonder if it is possible to disable using `__sprintf_chk()`?

Comment: Can you write your own `__sprintf_chk()` so that the linker doesn't pull the from the library?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to replace all calls to sprintf in your program from this:

```
 sprintf(params...);
```

into

```
 (sprintf)(params...);
```

This will disable any preprocessor-based sprintf-changing (* only if sprintf was changed using function-like macro like in the case of `__sprintf_chk`).

For gcc there are options `-fno-stack-protector -fno-mudflap`. May be also `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` (for any glibc)

For Ubuntu and debian there are pages with security features list: http://wiki.debian.org/Hardening and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features
Some used compiler flags are listed here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags

And there is a paper about SSP (stack-protector) and Fortify_source (glibc):
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/ssp.txt

PS: the same for __fgets_chk __gets_chk __printf_chk __fprintf_chk __vprintf_chk __vfprintf_chk __vsprintf_chk __wmemcpy_chk __wmemmove_chk  __wmempcpy_chk __wmemset_chk __wcscpy_chk __wcpcpy_chk __wcsncpy_chk __wcpncpy_chk __wcscat_chk __wcsncat_chk __swprintf_chk __vswprintf_chk __fwprintf_chk __wprintf_chk __vfwprintf_chk __vwprintf_chk  __fgetws_chk __wcrtomb_chk __mbsrtowcs_chk __wcsrtombs_chk __mbsnrtowcs_chk __wcsnrtombs_chk __memcpy_chk __memmove_chk __mempcpy_chk __memset_chk __strcpy_chk __strncpy_chk __stpncpy_chk __strcat_chk and some others

Comment: That's generally true of almost *any* standard C library function, that it can be implemented as a preprocessor macro. Using parens forces your code to use the actual function instead of the macro.

Comment: @DavidRTribble, this parens trick has never worked for me with `-O3`. In this case the only thing that worked was `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` or `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE`.

Comment: Compile with `-Wl,--wrap=sprintf` and link with `--wrap=sprintf`. You will need a separate code module for `__wrap_sprintf`. Then you can use the accepted answer without changing any code. I personally don't like turning off warnings for lots of code. See also [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25804940/4329358).

Perhaps there is a way you can change your build  system so that `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` is only given for certain code modules.

Answer (score 6):

> This __sprintf_chk() seems to check buffer overflow by examining stack frames.
>   ...
>   For my research purpose, I wonder if it is possible to disable using __sprintf_chk()?

I believe that's from `FORTIFY_SOURCE`. There's quite a few functions guarded like that. I believe the following will work for you:

```
CFLAGS += -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
```

Alternately, you might be able to:

```
CFLAGS += -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
```

---

Related: if I encounter software in the field that disables `FORTIFY_SOURCE`, then I file a security defect against it. Its OK to disable ot for Debug and Testing, but its not appropriate for production software.

---

Related, here's a [potentially incomplete] list of functions that can be protected with `FORTIFY_SOURCE`:

- memcpy
- mempcpy
- memmove
- memset
- stpcpy
- strcpy
- strncpy
- strcat
- strncat
- sprintf
- snprintf
- vsprintf
- vsnprintf
- gets

See [Difference between gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 and -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517526/difference-between-gcc-d-fortify-source-1-and-d-fortify-source-2).