# difference between gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 and -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2

Tags: security, gcc, glibc, fortify-source

Can someone point out the difference between `gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1` and `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`? I guess `=2` is more secure? I haven't been able to find a list which lists differences point by point.

I have also read that `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` should be used with `-O2`, otherwise not all features would be available. Also here i haven't found a list which would specify the regressions in detail. I would especially be interested to compile with `-Os` as the target is a device with not so much flash memory.

Any hints on where this is documented welcome!

Comment: Not sure if you have seen these so: (1) The patch which included GCC support for this (with some details on differences between `=1` and `=2`) is [**here**](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2004-09/msg02055.html); (2) The 'feature test macros' man page with an entry about `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` is [**here**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

From the manual page for the Feature Test Macros ([`man 7 feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html))

> #### **`_FORTIFY_SOURCE`** (since glibc 2.3.4)
>
> Defining this macro causes some lightweight checks to be performed to detect some buffer overflow errors when employing various string and memory manipulation functions (for example, `memcpy`, `memset`, `stpcpy`, `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `strcat`, `strncat`, `sprintf`, `snprintf`, `vsprintf`,  `vsnprintf`, `gets`, and wide character variants thereof). For some functions, argument consistency is checked; for example, a check is made that `open` has been supplied with a *mode* argument when the specified flags include **`O_CREAT`**. Not all problems are detected, just some common cases.
>
> If **`_FORTIFY_SOURCE`** is set to 1, with compiler optimization level 1 (*`gcc -O1`*) and above, checks that shouldn't change the behavior of conforming programs are performed.
>
> With **`_FORTIFY_SOURCE`** set to 2, some more checking is added, but some conforming programs might fail.
>
> Some of the checks can be performed at compile time (via macros logic implemented in header files), and result in compiler warnings; other checks take place at run time, and result in a run-time error if the check fails.
>
> Use of this macro requires compiler support, available with `gcc` since version 4.0.

Moreover, the article [Enhance application security with FORTIFY_SOURCE](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/enhance-application-security-fortifysource) (March 2014) says:

- `gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1` adds checks at compile-time only (some headers are necessary as `#include <string.h>`)
- `gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` also adds checks at run-time (detected buffer overflow terminates the program)

Essentially, `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` level 2 is more secure, but is a slightly riskier compilation strategy; if you use it, make sure you have very strong regression tests for your compiled code to prove the compiler hasn't introduced any unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Is there any indication, on when the conforming programs might fail?

Comment: `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1` adds at least one runtime check: It enables use of `__longjmp_chk` instead of `__longjmp`, that former of which checks that you don't jump "downwards" in the stack.

Comment: _"level 2 is more secure, but is a slightly riskier"_ — what sounds risky is the potential overflows; is level 2 non-conformant assuming you have software that has no code with buffer overflows?

Answer (score 27):

https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2004-09/msg02055.html goes into more detail than [`feature_test_macros(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

Here's the relevant excerpt, lightly edited/reformatted for clarity:

> The difference between `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1` and `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`
> is e.g. for
>
> ```
>   struct S {
>       struct T {
>         char buf[5];
>         int x;
>       } t;
>       char buf[20];
>   } var;
> ```
>
> With `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1`,
>
> ```
>   strcpy (&var.t.buf[1], "abcdefg");
> ```
>
> is not considered an overflow (object is whole `var`), while
> with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`
>
> ```
>   strcpy (&var.t.buf[1], "abcdefg");
> ```
>
> will be considered a buffer overflow.
>
> Another difference is that with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`, `%n`
> in format strings of the most common `*printf` family functions
> is allowed only if it is stored in read-only memory (usually
> string literals, `gettext`'s `_("%s string %n")` is fine too), but
> usually when an attacker attempts to exploit a format string
> vulnerability, `%n` will be somewhere where the attacker could
> write it into.