# Is there any motivation of using GCC __builtin_object_size at source code level?

Tags: c, gcc

I know this is not new, but recently I came across the topic of GCC __builtin_object_size() function. For what I read from the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html), it states that the intended use can be as follows:

> > The intended use can be e.g.
>
> ```
> #undef memcpy
> #define bos0(dest) __builtin_object_size (dest, 0)
> #define memcpy(dest, src, n) \
>   __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, n, bos0 (dest))
>
> char *volatile p;
> char buf[10];
> /* It is unknown what object p points to, so this is optimized
>    into plain memcpy - no checking is possible.  */
> memcpy (p, "abcde", n);
>
> ... // more codes
> ```

Is there any advantage of directly using it at the source code level instead of enabling the D_FORTIFY_SOURCE flag when compiling? Are there actually real life examples that benefit from the use of __builtin_object_size()?

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how the [`_FORTIFY_SOURCE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604146/918959) works with `memcpy`!

But there might certainly be *other* functions besides the standard library ones that would benefit from object pointer range check.

Comment: But i checked on the preprocessing output of GCC compiler and it seems that FORTIFY_SOURCE doesn't replace functions using macro approach. Is it possible there could be a difference between these two approaches?