# C "error: longjmp causes uninitialized stackframe" when using longjmp

Tags: c, memory, setjmp

I'm trying to build a simple cooperative multithreading library in C. Basically, it is possible to create threads using `thread_create`, add them to the runqueue with `thread_queue`, and then execute them to completion using `thread_exec`. Within the function that is assigned to a thread, it is possible to call `thread_yield` to put the current thread at the end of the runqueue and continue with the next thread.

Because the threads may be interrupted, their stacks are heap-allocated. I then use `setjmp` in `thread_yield` to remember the current state of execution, and `longjmp` in the `dispatch`-function to resume a thread.

For some reason, when running with compiler optimizations, I get the following error:

```
*** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***: terminated
```

I do not get this error when compiling with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`, and get the expected output:

```
started at main
printing from 1, now yielding
printing from 2, now yielding
printing from 3, now yielding
printing from 1, now yielding
printing from 2, now yielding
printing from 3, now yielding
printing from 1, now yielding
printing from 2, now yielding
printing from 3, now yielding
returned from thread
returned from thread
returned from thread
finished at main
```

I tried implementing saving and restoring of the `rsp`-register, but to no avail. I'd like to get this working without disabling compiler inserted safety checks and would appreciate any suggestions.

Here's the full code:

threads.c

```
#include "threads.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct thread* head_thread = NULL;
struct thread* tail_thread = NULL;
size_t initial_rbp = 0;

jmp_buf threading_start_ctx;

// create a thread executing f(arg)
struct thread* thread_create(void (*f)(void*), void* arg) {
    // allocate stack of one megabyte
    size_t stack_size = 1 << 20;
    struct thread* thread = (struct thread*) malloc(sizeof(struct thread));
    thread->next = NULL;
    thread->f = f;
    thread->arg = arg;
    thread->stack_ptr = malloc(stack_size);
    thread->stack_size = stack_size;
    thread->has_run = false;
    thread->rbp = 0;
    return thread;
}

// add a thread to back queue
void thread_queue(struct thread* thread) {
    if (!tail_thread) {
        head_thread = thread;
    } else {
        tail_thread->next = thread;
    }
    tail_thread = thread;
    thread->next = NULL;
}

// yield from thread, transfering execution to another thread
void thread_yield(void) {
    // save rbp
    asm("movq %%rbp, %[RBP]" : [RBP] "=rm" (head_thread->rbp) :);
    if (!setjmp(head_thread->jmp_buf)) {
        // if jmp was just set, schedule a different thread and execute it 
        schedule();
        dispatch();
    } 
    // restore rbp
    asm("movq %[RBP], %%rbp" : : [RBP] "rm" (head_thread->rbp));
}

// reschedule threads
static void schedule(void) {
    // only swap if more than one thread
    if (head_thread != tail_thread) {
        struct thread* current = head_thread;
        head_thread = head_thread->next;
        tail_thread->next = current;
        tail_thread = current;
        tail_thread->next = NULL;
    }
}

// execute current head thread
static void dispatch(void) {
    if (head_thread) {
        // stack grows downwards, therefore add offset
        size_t stack_top = (size_t) head_thread->stack_ptr + head_thread->stack_size;
        if (!head_thread->has_run) {
            head_thread->has_run = true;
            // set up rbp and rsp to thread stack
            asm(
                "movq %[StackTop], %%rbp\n"
                "movq %[StackTop], %%rsp" 
                : : [StackTop] "r" (stack_top)
            );
            // execute thread
            head_thread->f(head_thread->arg);

            printf("returned from thread\n");

            // returned from thread, load starting rbp 
            asm("movq %[RBP], %%rbp" : : [RBP] "rm" (initial_rbp));
            longjmp(threading_start_ctx, 1);
        } else {
            // load rbp of current head and continue where it yielded
            asm("movq %[RBP], %%rbp": : [RBP] "rm" (head_thread->rbp));
            longjmp(head_thread->jmp_buf, 1);
        }
    }
}

// start executing queued threads
void thread_exec(void) {
    // save starting rbp
    asm("movq %%rbp, %[RBP]" : [RBP] "=rm" (initial_rbp) :);
    if (setjmp(threading_start_ctx)) {
        // if arrive from longjmp, free current head
        struct thread* next = head_thread->next;
        free(head_thread->stack_ptr);
        free(head_thread);
        head_thread = next;
        if (!head_thread) {
            tail_thread = NULL;
        }
    }
    if (head_thread) {
        dispatch();
    }
}
```

threads.h

```
#ifndef THREADS_H_
#define THREADS_H_

#include <stddef.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct thread {
    struct thread* next;
    void (*f)(void*);
    void* arg;
    void* stack_ptr;
    size_t stack_size;
    bool has_run;
    size_t rbp;
    jmp_buf jmp_buf;
};

struct thread* thread_create(void (*f)(void*), void* arg);
void thread_queue(struct thread* t);
void thread_yield(void);
void thread_exec(void);

static void dispatch(void);
static void schedule(void);

#endif  // THREADS_H_
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "threads.h"

static int a3 = 3;

void arg_printer(void* arg) {
    int id = *(int*)arg;
    if (id == 1) {
        thread_queue(thread_create(arg_printer, &a3));
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("printing from %i, now yielding\n", id);
        thread_yield();
    }    
}

int main() {
    printf("started at main\n");
    
    int a1 = 1;
    int a2 = 2;

    thread_queue(thread_create(arg_printer, &a1));
    thread_queue(thread_create(arg_printer, &a2));

    thread_exec();
    printf("finished at main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason, when running with compiler optimizations, I get the following error:
>
> ```
> *** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***: terminated
> ```

Someone who also encountered such a problem put it [this way](https://github.com/sagemath/cysignals/issues/73#issuecomment-371909263):

> The problem is that the "longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame" is really a false positive. I'm abusing the stack in ways beyond the imagination of glibc.

The "fortified" (checked) [`longjmp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517526/difference-between-gcc-d-fortify-source-1-and-d-fortify-source-2#comment102425409_16604146) doesn't take heap-allocated stacks into account; after all, `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` is to perform checks of standard *conforming programs*.

> I'd like to get this working without disabling compiler inserted safety checks and would appreciate any suggestions.

You don't have to disable `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` everywhere; your program works if you just disable it for the *threads.c* compilation unit, where the critical `longjmp` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that anymore (assuming it was ever valid). Returning from a function that invokes `setjmp()` and then trying to `longjmp()` back in has always invoked undefined behavior. Right now it's actually catching it.

I'm going to take a wild guess and say you found this in an old book. I remember a very similar technique that used to work long ago, but nothing like this works now. The problem is compiler optimizations are going to hose everything. If you want lightweight user-scheduled threads it's a lot harder to implement than it once was. I would just plain do the whole thing in assembly now if I were you.

Comment: I understand that jumping to a function which has already returned is ub. But in this case, after calling `setjmp` in `thread_yield`, `dispatch` is called which will `longjmp` to another thread. Therefore, the `thread_yield` where `setjmp` was originally called never returns.