# Conforming but failing code when FORTIFY_SOURCE set to 2

Tags: c++, c, security, compiler-warnings

The man page here(https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), says "With
_FORTIFY_SOURCE set to 2, some more checking is added, but some conforming programs might fail."
Is there any example on Ubuntu 20.01 that confirms or validates this?

Comment: 1. Search google for `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` ; 2. click on the second answer : [_FORTIFY_SOURCE: explained](https://p0lycarp.github.io/2019/fortify/) ; read it ; done.

Comment: Thanks Valery S. The question was after doing some basic searches. I have read (rather checked) the code that is mentioned in the link you shared already. It does work (except that the result slightly differs from what is mentioned in link for FORTIFY_SOURCE=2. And that is due to stack-protection enabled by default in gcc Ubuntu 20.01 - checksec.sh confirms stack-protection is enabled.  I may be wrong, but I acknowledge that the article was written in 2019). But, I was looking for some more examples with WHY and WHEN just to be sure.  That is something that I may be missing in my search.

Comment: You're welcome ; It's all about program hardening ; this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517526/difference-between-gcc-d-fortify-source-1-and-d-fortify-source-2) could shed some light on this.